# SQL Server 2014: report text of query executed via shortcut in query window

Tags: sql, sql-server, keyboard-shortcuts, sql-server-2014

I was searching for a way to automatically execute some common queries that I use using a keyboard shortcut in SQL Server 2014.

I found that this is possible to accomplish setting a keyboard shortcut in `Menu -> Tools -> Options -> Keyboard` (there are already 3 stored procedures saved, `sp_who`, `sp_lock`, `sp_help`), so my main issue is resolved.

For example I can set CTRL + 3 to execute

```
SELECT ID FROM MY_TABLE
```

What I miss though is that in this way the executed query text (`SELECT ID FROM MY_TABLE`) doesn't show in the query window.

Maybe this is trivial but sometimes I need to use that query as a starting point to write other queries, so it would be useful to have the query text.

Answer (score 1):

What about using snippets instead: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492130(v=sql.120).aspx

"A Transact-SQL code snippet is a template you can use as a starting point when writing new Transact-SQL statements in the Database Engine Query Editor."